# Constant location request on startup

Tags: android, android-studio, popup, location

So I am trying to make an app in Android Studio which needs location settings turned on and therefor I wanted to make that window pop up in onCreate that asks if you would like to turn on location settings. But after you press Abort I dont know how to bring that window back again...
Is there a way to do so? Because I have seen in some apps like Tinder, that they won't start until you have pressed a few times on the Abort button.

```
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result;
    final static int REQUEST_LOCATION = 199;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);

        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

        result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());

        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                final Status status = result.getStatus();
                Log.d("Status: ", result.toString());
                //final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                        // requests here.
                        //...
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                        // a dialog.
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(
                                    MainActivity.this,
                                    REQUEST_LOCATION);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        //...
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        Log.d("onActivityResult()", Integer.toString(resultCode) + "," + Integer.toBinaryString(requestCode));

        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case REQUEST_LOCATION:
                switch (resultCode)
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    {
                        // All required changes were successfully made
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Location enabled by user!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    }
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    {
                        // The user was asked to change settings, but chose not to
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Location not enabled, user cancelled.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    }
                    default:
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
```

Comment: Post the relevant code snippets.

Comment: I posted the code now

Answer (score 0):

Create methode

```
private void mGoogleApiClientConnect(){
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

and call it here :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mGoogleApiClientConnect();
}
```

and here :

```
case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
     {
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Location not enabled, user cancelled.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          mGoogleApiClient.connect();
          break;
     }
```